# UITabController in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have tab controller created through storyboards with a custom implementation (simple buttons and labels) with hidden default bar. This all works as expected and can navigate the various views. However on a couple of my views I need to use a UIScrollView but would like the tab bar controls moved to the bottom on the scrollview, you would have to scroll to bottom to access them.  How would I implement such a configuration?  I am using XCode 4.3, ARC and Storyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create your own implementation of a UIView containing tabs and put that at the bottom of your UIScrollView.

The UITabBarController must be the root of your window. In other words, a UIViewController inside of a UITabBarController can contain a UIScrollView, but you cannot put a UITabBarController inside of another UIViewController (or within a UIScrollView).

From the [UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the
>   root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar
>   interface should never be installed as a child of another view
>   controller.

Comment: I accepted this answer since as @CondradShultz said it is the correct technical answer.

Answer (score 4):

@MichaelFrederick has given you the correct *technical* answer to your question.  I am now going to give you some higher level *design* feedback.

**Please don't do this.**

What you have described sounds incredibly confusing.  One purpose of `UITabBar` is to provide context to the user as to what "mode" they are in.  By hiding it, you deny the user this contextual information.

It also means that if the user wants to quickly switch modes (tabs), you are forcing them to scroll.

If you absolutely need maximum screen real estate for a scroll view (for, say, a large image), please consider presenting a modal view controller instead.  This gives you what you want, but does so without any messy subclassing, custom tabs (which invariably won't behave quite right), or usability issues.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I will push back on the client that is demanding such a layout, as I agree making the user scroll for navigation is a bad idea.  If they insist on the full screen views changing the navigation scheme will be the better option.

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely agree with Conrad and Michael is correct in everything except I don't think you would need to create your own custom tab bar. You should be able to use `UITabBar` directly without using `UITabBarController`.

I will not give you any more hints on how to do that besides reading the documentation, because Conrad is absolutely right. **It's very bad design.**